# Find $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}}{\sqrt{i^2+i}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

$$\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{\sqrt{i+1}-\sqrt{i}}{\sqrt{i^2+i}}$$

I have tried simplifying but I get $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}}$$ which is subtraction of two divergent series and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Actually splitting the series is fine because they are finite (aka it doesn't diverge), but instead write out the first few terms of the unsplit sum and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.  This is a telescoping *finite* sum.  The comment about infinite series is irrelevant because the upper index is $n$, not $\infty$.

We have $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} - \sum_{i=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}},$$ where we have shifted the index of the second summation by $1$.